# XML node with same name in another node

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

The XML I want to parse looks like this:

```
<root>
    <group>
        <somethingelse>
            <group></group>
        </somethingelse>
    </group>
</root>
```

As you can see, there is a `<group>` in the hierarchy of another `<group>`. Parsing it with `BeautifulStoneSoup` puts the inner `<group>` outside of the outter one (see below example).

How can I prevent this and keep the inner `<group>` at the place it is defined?

---

**Code**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

xml = """
    <root>
        <group>
            <somethingelse>
                <group></group>
            </somethingelse>
        </group>
    </root>
"""

def main():
    doc = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
    print doc.prettify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Result**

```
<root>
 <group>
  <somethingelse>
  </somethingelse>
 </group>
 <group>
 </group>
</root>
```

Comment: Any reason you are still using BeautifulSoup 3? BS4 together with `lxml` handles this far better.

Comment: It's the version I got with `pip` and I read that `bs4` is still in beta [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Quick%20Start). `pip install bs4` didn't work either. BeautifulSoup 3 was already installed on my system and `lxml` was not, so I didn't see a good reason to upgrade until now.

Comment: `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the most recent version of BeautifulSoup? Using BeautifulSoup4, I managed to get this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="xml")
print doc.prettify()
```

Result was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <group>
  <somethingelse>
   <group/>
  </somethingelse>
 </group>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to BeautifulSoup 4, and install the `lxml` parser. This combination handles XML correctly:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
>>> print doc.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <group>
  <somethingelse>
   <group/>
  </somethingelse>
 </group>
</root>
```

Install both projects with:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 lxml
```